# jQuery scroll to next element, uncaught type error

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to create  a slider that will scroll to the next element.

I am using an `<ul>` and numerous `<li>` tags, I have everything styled exactly how I want it to however JS is returning the following error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined`

The JS I have is below or view a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJPJr/):

```
var currentElement = $("li .listofyears:first");

// completely ignoring boundaries

$("#NavigateBackward").click(function() {
    currentElement = currentElement.prev();
    scrollTo(currentElement);
});

$("#NavigateForward").click(function() {
    currentElement = currentElement.next();
    scrollTo(currentElement);    
});

function scrollTo(element) {
    $(window).scrollLeft(element.position().left);   
}
```

my html is as below:

```
<div id="years_arrows">
            <span class="nav_arrows" ><img src="http://iconify.it/wp-content/icons-large-alt/arrow-left.png" id="NavigateBackward" /></span>
         <span class="nav_arrows aaa" ><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Right-facing-Arrow-icon.jpg" id="NavigateForward"/></span>
       <div id="slider">
        <div id="yearslistwrapper">
                <ul class="yearslist">
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2003</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2004</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2004</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2005</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2006</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2007</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2009</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2012</a></li>                       
                    <li class="listofyears"><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- END UL yearslist -->
            </div> <!--End slider-->

                </div> <!-- End years_arrows div -->
```

Comment: When going about it like this, make sure to test whether the element exists or not.  In your `scrollTo` function, use `if(element.length)` or `if(element.length > 0)`, which will prevent an error from being thrown. Reason an error appears in the first place is you can't find the position of an ***unknown/undefined*** object.

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
var currentElement = $("li.listofyears").first();
// completely ignoring boundaries

$("#NavigateBackward").click(function() {
    currentElement = $(currentElement).prev();
    scrollTo(currentElement);
});

$("#NavigateForward").click(function() {
    currentElement = currentElement.next();
    scrollTo(currentElement);    
});

function scrollTo(element) {
    $('.yearslist li').show();
    $('.yearslist li').not(element).hide();
}
```

forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QYmKJ/

Comment: Best solution amongst us :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect, and therefore not matching any elements. If the jQuery object you call `previous()` on is empty (contains no matched elements) it returns `undefined`.

Your selector:

```
$("li .listofyears:first");
```

That's looking for the first element with the class `listofyears` **inside** a `<li>` element. However, you want the first `<li>` element with that class, so remove the space:

```
$("li.listofyears:first");
```

There are other problems that will need to be solved after that. For example, if you click the previous button when looking at the first element, there won't be a previous element to find, and you'll get the same problem. You'll need to code around that (likely do nothing if there isn't a previous element).

Comment: that doesnt help the scrolling

Comment: @Gurtarandeep Like I said, there are other problems that need to be solved after. This is the cause of the error you're seeing, the fact that your code doesn't work once you've fixed that is unrelated. I'm not here to write the entire thing for you.

Comment: @davidkonrad See above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing your li's in wrong way

Line

```
var currentElement = $("li .listofyears:first");
```

Should be

```
var currentElement = $("li.listofyears:first");
```

your code is looking for elements with class listofyears inside `<li>` tag & not `<li>` tag with class listofyears.

Check fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qafjM/

Comment: that didn't work also you removed the styling on the jsfiddle so your example doesn't actually work :(

Comment: @Gurtarandeep  sorry but I don’t see any styling in your html either..So its difficult to analyse what effect you trying to achieve. I don’t say that this is entire solution. But I have just pointed the bug in your code cause of which the mentioned error by you was occurring